# Terraform maven preview feature unrecognised

Tags: maven, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

artifact registry has a MAVEN format in preview. But when I do terraform apply in order to create a resource that has a preview feature, I have an error.

The resource:

```
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "my-maven-repo" {
  provider = google-beta
  project = "my-project"
  location = "europe-west4"
  repository_id = "my-maven-repo"
  description = "My maven repository"
  format = "MAVEN"
}
```

Error:

```
expected format to be one of [DOCKER], got MAVEN
```

In this [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/artifact_registry_repository), it states that MAVEN format is in preview.

My terraform version:

```
Terraform v1.1.4
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.38.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta v3.51.1
```

Comment: Since that is an error returned from the API and not Terraform or the provider, I would suspect it is related to the note in the doc: "You can only create alpha formats if you are a member of the alpha user group."

Comment: @MattSchuchard but this isn't an alpha feature, it's a preview one. Should be available.

Comment: I am merely quoting the documentation, and it is documentation that I did not write. If you disagree with the documentation, then I would encourage you to file an issue with Google Cloud and Hashicorp on their tracker for the provider: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues. You may be redirected to Google Cloud support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the google provider to 4.8 then doing `terraform init -upgrade` fixed it.